# Parsing Python to Golang - DateTime

Tags: python, datetime, go

I've been attempting to get a specific string output from pyhtons datetime
(2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z), so that I can easily parse it in golang using time.Parse.

I tried (in python)

```
datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

Which will give me something like this: "2018-11-06T22:48:50.002750Z"

And when I try to parse it like this in Golang:

```
dtLayout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
dateStr := "2018-11-06T22:48:50.002750Z"

parsedDate, err := time.Parse(dtLayout, dateStr)
if err != nil {
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error: %v", err)
    }
```

I get this error:

> 2018/11/06 16:49:11 error: parsing time "2018-11-06T22:48:50.002750Z" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z": cannot parse "750Z" as "Z"

There's probably an easy way to do this using just milliseconds, but I'm stubborn and feel like I'm close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zeros in the fractional seconds must match the number of characters exactly, and as your error states, the portion after `750Z` doesn't match the corresponding portion of the format string.

You can add the correct number of zeros, like `"2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000Z"`, or use `9` as a more flexible format.

```
dtLayout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.9Z"
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dyC0OXUnhhu

Comment: The 9! That's the kind if solution I was looking for. Thank you so much, that works perfectly and doesn't feel too dirty :D